# Spark program on Windows cluster fails with error CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute a program on a Spark v2.0.0 Cluster on my Windows 10 laptop. There is a master node on port 31080 and slave node on 32080. The cluster is using the Standalone manager and am using JDK 1.8, with a custom work directory for the slave.

When the program is submitted via spark-submit or through Eclipse > Run program, I get the below error, and the executor goes in a loop (a new executor is created, and fails continuously). Please guide.

> Executor updated: app-20160906203653-0001/0 is now RUNNING
>
> Executor updated: app-20160906203653-0001/0 is now FAILED (java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""D:\jdk1.8.0_101"\bin\java"
>
> (in directory "D:\spark-work\app-20160906203653-0001\0"):
>
> CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)
>
> Executor app-20160906203653-0001/0 removed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""D:\jdk1.8.0_101"\bin\java" (in directory
>
> "D:\spark-work\app-20160906203653-0001\0"): CreateProcess error=5,
>
> Access is denied
>
> Removal of executor 0 requested

Comment: It seems you don't have Administrator privilege. Try to open a command prompt as "Run As Administrator" and then run your program (or) Change D:\spark-work folder privilege and add 'everyone'

Comment: Thanks for your comments Nambari... this does not seem to work, tried both options.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.. I was starting my master and slaves through windows batch scripts. These were invoking an env script which was setting JAVA_HOME, SCALA_HOME and SPARK_HOME. The paths were enclosed in double quotes. Hence the issue. Removing the double quotes fixed the issue... no Admin priviliges or changes needed.